# Fill dataset only partially based on condition

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

With the `DataSet` created in Visual Studio, is there a way to load rows based on a global condition. Lets say with the following tables I only want to load rows where the `Type`'s `Reference` is set to 1:

```
Type
Type_ID  Name       References
0        Simple     0
1        Another    0
2        Relevant   1
3        Reference  1

Main
Main_ID  Type_ID  Name
0        0        Don't include
1        2        Include this
2        3        And that

Details
Details_ID  Main_ID  Other data
0           2        Blah blah blah
```

Is it possible to define a condition which then applies to all tables/adapters. So I can say "Reference = 1" and it would only load the relevant rows (so all except those with `Type_ID`s set to 0, 1 and `Main_ID` set to 0). Like saying: Only load those rows where it can satisfy the constraints.

Basically a "programmatic" version of these SQL queries:

```
SELECT Type.* FROM Type WHERE Type.Reference = 1
SELECT Main.* FROM Main NATURAL JOIN Type WHERE Type.Reference = 1
SELECT Details.* FROM Details NATURAL JOIN Main NATURAL JOIN Type WHERE Type.Reference = 1
```

At the moment I only have something like this, which could break when I overlook a table and call the wrong query there:

```
typeDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet.Type);
mainDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet.Main);
detailsDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet.Details);
```

Comment: it's ```ado.net``` or ```entity framework```?

Comment: It is `ado.net`

Comment: In ado.net you write the full SQL by yourself?

Comment: Sorry, the original question didn't really explain my intentions. I've edited it accordingly: I was wondering if there is a way to only load "valid rows" without manually adding a SQL query everywhere.